# AlarmManager doesn't seem to be working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm trying to schedule a method to be called using `AlarmManager`, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've looked at other examples and theirs isn't working for me. So I'm thinking it's something from my code. Here's the `AlarmManager` code:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, KinectReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(SplashScreenActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

And my broadcast receiver:

```
public class KinectReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notify)
                .setContentTitle("Kinect")
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent))
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentText("Your Kinects and Likes have been refilled. Now get to swiping")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(uri)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                        .bigText("Your Kinects and Likes have been refilled. Now get to swiping"))
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 100, 500, 100, 500, 100 });

        Intent targetIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        targetIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        targetIntent.putExtra("action", "main");
        targetIntent.putExtra("id", "");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }
}
```

Neither the Toast nor the Notification show.

The `AlarmManager` code is in the first thing that runs in my launcher activity, in case that helps. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `<receiver>` element in the manifest for `KinectReceiver`? Also note that `HOUR_OF_DAY` is based on the 24-hour clock, so 2 is 2am.

Comment: No. I don't. How do I implement that. And yes, I know how the `Calender` object works. I was just using that to test. It was 2 am when I tested it

Comment: Is this alright: `<receiver android:name=".utility.KinectReceiver" />`

Comment: Yep, that's it, assuming it's in `utility/`. Make sure it's between the `<application>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please register ur receiver in manifeast file like this

In application tag

```
<receiver
   android:name=".KinectReceiver">
```

Comment: Grear happy to help u my frd

Comment: Quick question though. How do I go about cancelling an ongoing alarm schedule?

Answer (score 1):

Second question is how to cancel alarm

Here is ur answer

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmActivity.class);
   pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(CellManageAddShowActivity.this,
       id, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   pendingIntent.cancel();
   alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

The main thing that you will need is:

1).Create pending intent with the same id and appropriate intent FLAG.
2).Cancel that pending intent.
3).Cancel the alarm using alarm manager.

Comment: Nope this will cancel alarm which u have set using same id with which which u have scheduled one alaram

Comment: If u have used same id for all alarm than it will cancel all..u can check other PendingIntent flags also for cancel all alarms from google developer site